# App Crashes on Buy Subscription when first time launched

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I'm working on this **subscription** system for my app,it took a few days.But as I'm working more on it,it makes more problems.
Sometimes it happens that the app crashes when clicking on **buy subscription**.

Also I'm having the problem of not knowing when to stop the **Please wait.... alert**.I need to place the code in:

```
            case .Purchasing:

                self.alert_show()

                break
```

But I don't know where to end it,I need to know the information when is the alert from iTunes loaded than to stop the **Please wait....** alert.

The biggest problem right now that I'm facing is the crashing sometimes when i click on the **Buy Button**.

The crashing happens when first time launching the app,and clicking one the **Buy Subscription**.
Here is the code for the **Buy Subscription:**

```
@IBAction func buy_sub(sender: AnyObject) {
        let payment:SKPayment = SKPayment(product: product)
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(payment)
}
```

Here is the error that I'm getting.

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value..

I would like to share with you my source code of the subscription.If you have any advices what to add,or to correct or to correct this problems that i have it would be great.

Here is the full source code of the Subscription View:

```
class SubscriptionViewController: UIViewController  ,SKPaymentTransactionObserver, SKProductsRequestDelegate {

    //var productID = ""
     var product: SKProduct!

    @IBOutlet var buy_trial_button: UIButton!

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {




        if(SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {


        } else {
            buy_trial_button.enabled = false
            message_alert("Please enable IAPS to continue(Credit card information required  in your iTunes account).")
        }

        //validateReceipt()

        let keystore = NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.defaultStore()


        if keystore.objectForKey("expiration_date") != nil{
            let expiration: AnyObject? = keystore.objectForKey("expiration_date")

                let today = NSDate()

                let expiredate = expiration as! NSDate

                print("expiredate is  %@",expiredate,today)


               // var date1 = NSDate()
               // var date2 = NSDate()


            if(today.compare(expiredate) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending){
                print("today is later than expiredate")
                validateReceipt()
                print("Validating")



            }else if(today.compare(expiredate) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending){
                print("today is earlier than expiredate")
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("subscriptionPassed", sender: self)
            }


        }else{
        print("First time launch")
        }


    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
        self.getProductInfo()


        //SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
        //self.getProductInfo()
             // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {

    }



    @IBAction func private_policy(sender: AnyObject) {
        let openLink = NSURL(string : "http://arsutech.com/private_policy.php")
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(openLink!)
    }



    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {


        if(segue.identifier == "subscriptionPassed")
        {
        }

    }




    func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse){
        let products = response.products
        if products.count != 0
        {
            product = products[0] as SKProduct
            print(product.localizedTitle + "\n" + product.localizedDescription)

        }
    }



    func getProductInfo(){
        if (SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()){
            let productID:NSSet = NSSet(object: "com.sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
            let request:SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as! Set<String>)
            request.delegate = self
            request.start()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func buy_sub(sender: AnyObject) {
            let payment:SKPayment = SKPayment(product: product)
            SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(payment)
    }

    @IBAction func buy_pro(sender: AnyObject) {
        let openLink = NSURL(string : "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/home-workouts-exercises-mma/id1060747118?mt=8")
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(openLink!)
    }

    @IBAction func exit(sender: AnyObject) {
        exit(0)
    }






    func validateReceipt(){
        alert_show()

        let mainBundle = NSBundle.mainBundle() as NSBundle;
        let receiptUrl = mainBundle.appStoreReceiptURL;
        let isPresent = receiptUrl?.checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError(NSErrorPointer());

        if(isPresent == true){

            let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: receiptUrl! );
            // Create the JSON object that describes the request
            let requestContents  = NSMutableDictionary();
            //let encodeddata = data!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions());
            let encodeddata = data!.base64EncodedString();
            //print("encodeddata = \(encodeddata)");
            requestContents.setObject(encodeddata, forKey: "receipt-data");
            requestContents.setObject("c40f23af1aa44e159aezzzzzzzzzzzzzz", forKey: "password");
            var requestData : NSData?
            do{
                requestData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(requestContents, options: NSJSONWritingOptions());
            }catch{
              //  NSLog("Error in json data creation at verifyPaymentReceipt");
            }
            let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
            let file = "\(documentsPath)/requestData"

            if(NSFileManager.defaultManager().createFileAtPath(file, contents: data, attributes: nil)){
                NSLog("File %@ ",file);
            }
            else{
                //NSLog("error File %@ ",file);
            }

            if(requestData != nil){

                //let strRequestData = NSString(data: requestData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding);
                //print(" strRequestData = \(strRequestData)");
                // Create a POST request with the receipt data.
                //https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt
                //https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt

                let storeURL = NSURL(string: "https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt");
                let storeRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: storeURL!);
                storeRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST";
                storeRequest.HTTPBody = requestData;

                // Make a connection to the iTunes Store on a background queue.

                let queue = NSOperationQueue();
                NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(storeRequest, queue: queue, completionHandler: { (response : NSURLResponse?, data : NSData?, error : NSError?) -> Void in

                    if(error != nil){
                        //Handle Error

                    }
                    else{
                        let d = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding);

                       // NSLog("DATA:%@", d!);


                        let dataA = d!.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                        var jsonResponseInternal: NSMutableDictionary?
                        do{
                            jsonResponseInternal = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataA!,options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as? NSMutableDictionary;
                            //print(jsonResponseInternal);

                        }catch{
                            // NSLog("Parsing issue : verifyPaymentReceipt");
                        }



                        var jsonResponse: NSMutableDictionary?
                        do{
                            jsonResponse = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!,
                                options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as? NSMutableDictionary;
                            //print(jsonResponse);

                        }catch{
                           // NSLog("Parsing issue : verifyPaymentReceipt");
                        }

                        if(jsonResponse != nil){

                            if(jsonResponse != nil){


                                //NSLog("Expiration Date: %@", jsonResponse!);
                                //print("Passed")
                                /*
                                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "Purchase")
                                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
                                */
                                //self.performSegueWithIdentifier("subscriptionPassed", sender: self)





                                if jsonResponse!["status"] as? Int == 0 {

                                    //print("Sucessfully returned internal receipt data")
                                    if let receiptInfo: NSArray = jsonResponse!["latest_receipt_info"] as? NSArray {
                                        let lastReceipt = receiptInfo.lastObject as! NSDictionary

                                        var trial_period: Bool = false
                                        // Get last receipt
                                        //print("LAST RECEIPT INFORMATION \n",lastReceipt)
                                        print("Last from internal memory",lastReceipt["original_transaction_id"])

                                        //var is_trial = lastReceipt["is_trial_period"] as! Bool
                                        //var date_bought =
                                        //var date_expires =

                                        // Format date


                                        //print(is_trial)


                                        // Format date
                                        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
                                        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss VV"
                                        formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")

                                        // Get Expiry date as NSDate
                                        let subscriptionExpirationDate: NSDate = formatter.dateFromString(lastReceipt["expires_date"] as! String) as NSDate!
                                        print("\n   - DATE SUBSCRIPTION EXPIRES = \(subscriptionExpirationDate)")

                                        let currentDateTime = NSDate()
                                        print(currentDateTime)


                                        if var is_trial:Bool = false{
                                            if(lastReceipt["is_trial_period"] as? String == "Optional(\"true\")"){
                                                is_trial = true
                                                trial_period = is_trial
                                            }else if(lastReceipt["is_trial_period"] as? String == "Optional(\"false\")"){
                                                is_trial = false
                                                trial_period = is_trial
                                            }
                                        }



                                        if (subscriptionExpirationDate.compare(currentDateTime) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending) {

                                            self.alrt_close()

                                            print("Pass");
                                            print("The trial period is \(trial_period)")
                                            let keystore = NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.defaultStore()
                                            keystore.setObject(subscriptionExpirationDate,forKey:"expiration_date")
                                            keystore.synchronize()
                                            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("subscriptionPassed", sender: self)



                                        } else if (subscriptionExpirationDate.compare(currentDateTime) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending) {
                                            print("Not Pass");
                                            print("Subscription expired")
                                            self.alrt_close()
                                            //self.message_alert("Subscription expired")


                                        }

                                    }


                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

            }

        }

    }


    func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {

        for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
            if let trans:SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction{
                switch trans.transactionState {

                case .Purchasing:

                    //self.alrt_close()

                    break

                case .Deferred:
                    self.alert_show()
                    break

                case .Purchased:
                    alrt_close()
                    self.validateReceipt()
                    //self.setExpirationDate()
                    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                    //dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
                    break
                case .Failed:
                    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                    print("Not called Expired")
                    message_alert("Error while purchasing!")
                    break
                case .Restored:
                    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
                    print("Restored")
                    break

                default:
                    break

                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Alrt
    func message_alert(let message_A:String){
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "\(message_A)", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func alert_show(){
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Please wait...", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        alert.view.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        let loadingIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(10, 5, 50, 50)) as UIActivityIndicatorView
        loadingIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        loadingIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray
        loadingIndicator.startAnimating();
        alert.view.addSubview(loadingIndicator)
        presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func alrt_close(){
       self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: Which line is causing the unwrapping error? You have a lot of `!`. Consider `if let` or `guard`.

Comment: Also consider `RMStore` or similar packages to do the hard work. https://github.com/robotmedia/RMStore

Comment: I don't want to use pre done stuff.I want to learn it.

Comment: Waste no time learning an API that changes with OS upgrades. Leverage on `cocoapods` and other open source projects, vetted by thousand of engineers. You can still learn about In App Purchases & participate in open source projects: these two directions are compatible, and your code will be so much more robust.